# Forcing Windows roaming profile sync

Tags: windows-7, windows, roaming-profiles

In my company the user profile and directory are roaming profiles and are getting synced at startup/shutdown. This doesn't always work correctly and sometimes changes get lost. It happens when there are a lot of changes. This is why I'd like to perform a manual sync and maybe see some error messages.

Is there a way to perform a sync manually?

Comment: Now that I found out that this is actually called "roamin profile" I found http://www.thegeekpost.com/2012/01/24/tips-windows-7-roaming-profile-manual-sync/ but it only works with an admin account which I don't have :-/

Comment: Ask your IT staff on how this might be possible.